# How to insert and delete from and to the same table in the same query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there any way to select something from table A then delete & insert those records from/to table B (kind of updating B with values from A)?

Let's say I have two following tables:

```
------- Table A -------
id   name   value   id2
1    'a'    25      6
1    'a'    33      8
2    'c'    63      4

------- Table B -------
id   name   value   id3
1    'a'    12      6
2    'c'    63      7
5    'd'    18      9
```

I came up with this:

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *, xRank 
  FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, name ORDER BY id2 DESC) AS xRank 
    FROM A
  ) AS I 
  WHERE xRank = 1 AND <some other conditions>
), DLT AS (
  DELETE FROM B USING CTE T WHERE id=T.id AND name=T.name
)
INSERT INTO B (id, name, value) 
SELECT id, name, value 
FROM CTE T 
WHERE <some condition>;
```

This is working expect when it fails for "duplicate key value" error. However I thought maybe the delete is ran prior to insert but apparently they are executed is the same transaction.

At the end, Table B should become:

```
------- Table B -------
id   name   value   id3
1    'a'    33      NULL
2    'c'    63      NULL
5    'd'    18      9
```

Anyone has any simple way to do that (**without using temp tables and by doing only once the SELECT part of course**)?

Comment: Please explain the logic for `value` and `id3`.  It is not obvious.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry if my post is not clear. The idea is to delete & insert from/to the same table in one query, using some "key" columns (id, name in this example) in order to update other "common" column(s) (value). Uncommon column(s) (id3) have no impact and will be ignored.

Comment: . . Then why do the values change?

Comment: The whole point is to update common columns, which is "value" in this example if the key exists (insert simply if the key does not exists in table B). The "value" was previously 12 for key (1, 'a') in the table B. In table A we have let's say two new updates of the value for the same key (1, 'a') and we want to update table B with the latest one (id2 desc) which is 33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you have a unique constraint for `(id, name)` in `B`, I think that you need [`INSERT...ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html):

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *, xRank 
  FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, name ORDER BY id2 DESC) AS xRank 
    FROM A
  ) AS I 
  WHERE xRank = 1
)
INSERT INTO B (id, name, value) 
SELECT id, name, value 
FROM CTE 
ON CONFLICT(id, name) DO 
UPDATE 
SET value = EXCLUDED.value,
    id3 = NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qaV3TEDSYg59YWV9wkpt1T/2).
Results:

```
| id  | name | value | id3 |
| --- | ---- | ----- | --- |
| 1   | a    | 33    |     |
| 2   | c    | 63    |     |
| 5   | d    | 18    | 9   |
```

Comment: common columns are computed dynamically, here I simplified the situation. So hard coding columns in ON CONFLICT part does not work for me. Is there any way to just take values from table A if the column exists in table B and leave other columns in table B to NULL in case of conflicts?

Comment: I don't know how much you simplified the situation. My answer is for the question as you posted it. If your requirement is different then you can post a new question where you will not simplify the situation.

Comment: Fair enough. In fact it's possible to put in place your solution, I just need to write the columns dynamically in UPDATE part. But actually this solution is the best/simplest solution I found so far. In addition, getting rid of DELETE part will help to avoid dead tuples and less the need of autovacuum.

Answer (score 0):

Would a temp table work for you like this:

```
BEGIN;

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _temp
  (
  a_id int
  ,b_id int
  ,name text
  ,value int
  );
  
  INSERT INTO _temp
  SELECT <the logic from your CTE>;
  
  DELETE FROM B 
  JOIN _temp AS t
  ON t.b_id = b.id;
  
  INSERT INTO b
  SELECT <your insert from CTE>
  FROM _temp;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Sorry to not precise that, I don't want for some reasons to use temp table. I'll update my post to indicate that